# Pass schema name as a variable in postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have a table with schema names. I am writing a procedure to select schema name from the table and into a variable. The variable is then used to fetch records from the schema table.
Sample code below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE vasmol_master.sp_pushmt(
    )
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
    shortcodedatabase CHARACTER VARYING;
    services CHARACTER VARYING;
    BEGIN
         FOR shortcodedatabase IN SELECT dbase FROM vasmol_master.shortcode_services ORDER BY shortcode ASC LOOP
            services := shortcodedatabase ||'.smsservices';
            
            SELECT * FROM services;
        END LOOP;
    END

$BODY$;
```

Comment: See the manuals. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: From the answer I might have an idea what the question is, but I don't know what the problem is. Can you please add detail for both of these?

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation linked to in a comment by Richard Huxton explains, to substitute a variable identifier into a query, use `EXECUTE`. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Depending on the return values you want, your procedure could look something like the following. This uses format to create a query string, substituting in the schema name as an identifier (`%I`).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE vasmol_master.sp_pushmt()
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  shortcodedatabase CHARACTER VARYING;
BEGIN
  FOR shortcodedatabase IN
    SELECT dbase
    FROM vasmol_master.shortcode_services
    ORDER BY shortcode ASC
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I.smsservices', shortcodedatabase);
  END LOOP;
END
$BODY$;
```